# Creating polygon fill as seen in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, symbology, fill

The polygon fill for 'Urban parcels' in the following .gif animation looks really cool.

http://changelog.qgis.org/media/images/entries/5817785cf3d18db78669c2eb2c2be0cf606c3783.gif

(See also: http://changelog.qgis.org/en/qgis/version/2.16.0/)

Does anybody know how to create a polygon fill like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is not a new feature in 2.16, it's also possible at least with 2.14

You can combine several styles for one layer, so you can create such a visualization. In this particular case, I would recommend to combine a shapeburst fill, a line pattern fill and a simple fill. See also the following image for the different fill types: [image: style_qgis]

The inner white part is created by using the colors 'transparent' and 'white' at the shapeburst fill. Try also different values for the blur, until it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

In Layer Property --> Style --> for a symbol:

in "Symbol layer type" = Shapeburst fill,

and then, you can to choose your favorite configuration.